# Select multiple records from a table

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to enable multiple selection in my tableview and also i need to keep track of what i have selected (like save it to an array or something). My approach so far;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
   }

    cell.textLabel.text=[arrayobject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    bool xx = [[allmyselectedobjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] containsIndex:1];

        if (xx) {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        }else{
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        }

    return cell;
}
```

and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell *cell = [self.cuisineTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [self.allmyselectedobjects  insertObject:1 atIndex:indexPath.row];        
    } 
    else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [self.allmyselectedobjects  insertObject:0 atIndex:indexPath.row];
    }   
}
```

I could click multiple records, but when i scroll down i see other cells also ticked with the check mark (which i didn't select). I have been trying this for days now, can someone help me fix this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A given cell instance is recycled and used for many rows. Store your checked indexPathes but not the cells.

Comment: Ok and what might be the workaround for that, programatically ?

Comment: Use NSIndexSet as shown above to store the selected cells row index.

Comment: by meaning NSIndexSet, did you mean to change the type of  allmyselectedobjects to NSIndexSet and not NSMutableArray ?

Comment: Yes and to call it allMySelectedIndexes would reflect more precisely its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Right before

```
 Bool xx =
```

add this:

```
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using an NSIndexSet to store checked cells. So just insert the index of the selected cell and test it.

```
// Test
BOOL xx = [allmyselectedobjects containsIndex: indexPath.row]

// Selected cell
[allmyselectedobjects addIndex: indexPath.row]

// Unselected cell
[allmyselectedobjects removeIndex: indexPath.row]
```

Comment: No.. allmyselectedobjects  is a NSMutableArray which i am using to store the checked cells